# New GPU buzzing, heating up and wont turn off the fans (ON IDLE)

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, fan

I have a new GTX 1070 I bought yesterday.

The new GPU buzzing (really loudly) on idle, but when I stress test it or play a game the buzzing goes away (when I exit the test/game the buzzing comes back immediately)

Here is the steps for me to reproduce the problem:

- Restart PC (buzzing and GPU heating is gone)
- Playing around the computer for 10-20 min (sometimes less) (nothing specific!)
- Buzzing happens suddenly and when I check the temperature it keep raising but the fans try to cool it so it doesn't go above 60. (Again, all of this in idle! nothing is running, no game no video nothing)

I read on the internet about something called "Coil Whine" (or something similar) that will cause the buzzing, but everyone who has that will only hear it under GPU load!

So, I tried to check if some process is using my GPU and got nothing (Process Explorer), Tried to scan for viruses (which is unlikely, I don't download stuff randomly, only from reliable sources) and got nothing.

Only restarting the PC seem to make the buzzing go away but it come back after 10-20 minutes..

What can be the problem? how can I diagnose it? is it common thing?

By the way (if it will help) I got the Gigabyte GTX 1070 G1 Gaming.

If I am missing any information please let me know!

[Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PJ2If0jxhio) with a sound similar to mine :\

Specs:
Asus H170-M-Plus, i7-6700, 700W power (EDIT: the PSU is 5 years old and the model is: Fsp Aurum Gold 90, maybe he is the cause? how can I check that?)

**EDIT:**

Discovered that when there are programs working the GPU is buzzing, for example, when Firefox is running I hear the buzzing, and when I turn it off, the buzzing stops...

When the Firefox (for example) running, and I run a stress-test, the buzzing goes away, when I exit the stress-test the buzzing come back (Firefox still running).

Tested this with several program and got the same result (Firefox, Chrome, IExplorer, Photoshop, Visual Studio etc...), games not included! they only silent the card!

Comment: Good ole coil while. LinusTechTips has a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HP73edpQwgc) you can watch here that briefly explains what it is, and how it occurs. This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jtXAuIJchps) is a bit more descriptive. You could call Gigabyte and explain your situation and see if coil whine is an acceptable reason for an RMA. Also note that it may do the same thing if you do happen to get an RMA.

Comment: Also some users report a card having coil whine, and others do not. For instance I just got a GTX 1080. Some users posted that the card has terrible coil whine, while mine is completely silent.

Comment: @DrZoo Really? on idle? it is REALLY loud, loud as I can hear it from 3 4 meters away :\

Comment: Yeah, some people experience it while it's idling. I forgot to add in my first comment that getting a new PSU could possibly stop the coil whine. I would first contact Gigabyte and see if they will accept it as an RMA device. If the excessive whine continues after the RMA, I'd try a new PSU. Sorry about your annoying "feature."

Comment: @DrZoo I can only contact the store I bought from in my country, I went to there and they couldn't reproduce the noise.. (20 min of work~) I can go back to them but I want to try and test it on my own if I can speed things up

Comment: The more annoying thing for me, when I stress-test or play a game, the card is COMPLETELY SILENT!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52812/discussion-between-drzoo-and-zik332).