# New GPU Core Clock go high on programs (not games and stress-test)

Tags: graphics-card, gpu

This follow-up on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1173639/new-gpu-buzzing-heating-up-and-wont-turn-off-the-fans-on-idle), I found out using MSI AfterBurner, that when I use regular programs like Firefox, Chrome Photoshop and more that the Core Clock goes up to 1924(!!!) [which is way over what the GPU specs says](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5916#kf). (The 1924MHz is the only case where I get HUGE buzzing sound)

(This question is about the core clock going high when idle instead of low, not about the noise)

This is the situation:

- After restart the core clock goes back to 1590~.
- After opening some program (not games or stress-test) the core clockgoes to 1924 which result in buzzing.
- After closing previous program the core clock goes back to 1590~.
- If there is no program running and I open a game or stress-test the core clock goes to 1820~ like the specs says (NO BUZZING).
- **If some program is open and the core clock is at 1924, and I open a game or stress-test, the core clock goes to 1820~, and after closing the test or game the clock goes back to 1924 and the buzzing continues!**

I checked everything I can to test it and it seem like something is going on with the GPU, I mean, it literally goes overboard with the clock speed for NO reason. I checked if there is some program that use's the GPU and nothing did...

**EDIT: The "Buzzing" sound I mentioned is called "Coil Whine" as the previous question says.**

UPDATE!: **I found out that after I restart the computer and opening one of the programs that caused the high core clock & "Coil Whine", (RIGHT AFTER RESTART) the core clock speed DROPS to 240Mhz!** I don't know if it is normal or not :\

Comment: @Ramhound it is not the case, you can see the other question as well. and it is not only AfterBurner, I checked on other programs –

Comment: @Ramhound So how come the buzzing noise only come when the clock is at 1924? I didn't overclock the card.. I didn't touch anything of that sort.

Comment: @Ramhound The sound is not from the fan, the fan is at 32%.. the buzzing is something called "Coil Whine", and for me it only happens when the clock is at 1924 which is when I use regular program

Comment: @Ramhound I did not "accidently overclocked" it believe me. I checked. The site say's what the "default overclock" is, and it is above that.

Comment: @Ramhound No it is not a problem, but the "Coil Whine" coming only from that MHz. I don't know how and why but that's the case, I tested several times :\ Why would the GPU even go that high with simple programs like Firefox or Chrome?..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New GPU buzzing, heating up and wont turn off the fans (ON IDLE)](http://superuser.com/questions/1173639/new-gpu-buzzing-heating-up-and-wont-turn-off-the-fans-on-idle)

Comment: @Ramhound This question is about the core clock begin high... not about the noise... Deleted your comments and flagged this question, really?..

Comment: The issues are related.  Votes are anonymous.  Comments are designed to be temporary.  After you replied to my comments, they don't serve a purpose l, so I cleaned up my own comments